# Postgres Unnest or flatten a nested array inside of JSONB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, json, array

I've got a table `MY_TABLE` that has the following columns:

- User
- Name
- Data
- Purchased

Data is of the form :

```
       [{
           "Id": 1,
           "Attributes": [\"[\\\"[\\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Test123"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\"]\\\"]\"]
        },
        {
           "Id": 2,
           "Attributes": []
        },
        {
           "Id": 3,
           "Attributes": ["[\"[\\\"[\\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Test2\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\"]\\\"]\"]"]
        }]
```

However, what I want is:

```
    [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Attributes": ["Test"]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Attributes": []
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Attributes": ["Test2"]
    }]
```

I believe the problem occurred when the script below was run more than once.

```
jsonb_set(
    mycol,
    '{Attributes}',
    case when js ->> 'Attributes' <> '' 
        then jsonb_build_array(js ->> 'Attributes')
        else '[]'::jsonb
    end
)
```

I am unable to rollback the changes, so I have to remove the nested arrays manually. Does anyone know how I can go about doing so?

Instead of removing the nested arrays, I was thinking that I could extract the string and build a new array with that string as well. However, I am unsure of how to traverse the nested array to get the inner string

Comment: @McNets updated with my tag

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048673/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048673/postgres-unnest-a-nested-array-inside-of-jsonb  is no longer available.